# python program to calculate hour rate for time and half

Tags: python, payment

I have a simple python program that calculates pay based on hours and pay rate.  I want the program to calculate time and half for extra hours worked over 40.  Problem work for 40 hours.  Doesn't calculate correctly for over 40 hours:

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter hours: ")
rt = raw_input("Enter rate: ")
hours = float(hrs)
rate = float(rt)

if hours > 40:
    extra_hours = hours - 40
    extra_rate = rate * 1.5
    pay = rate * hours + (extra_rate * extra_hours)
    print "Pay:", pay
else:
    pay = rate * hours
    print "Pay:", pay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate too much extra rate for hours over 40. You first rate **all** hours at the normal rate, then add another 1.5 times the extra rate for the surplus.

Either use:

```
extra_hours = hours - 40
extra_rate = rate * 1.5
pay = rate * 40 + (extra_rate * extra_hours)
```

or limit the extra rate to just 0.5:

```
extra_hours = hours - 40
extra_rate = rate * 0.5
pay = rate * hours + (extra_rate * extra_hours)
```

Comment: Right! I was using hours in my calculation and NOT the standard 40. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

pay = rate * 40 + (extra_rate * extra_hours)